# accessing data from oracle db in windows service

Tags: c#, windows, oracle

im trying to create a windows service that will connect to an oracle db once an hour and pull some records and write those to a log file. the service i created runs, writes to the file on the intervals but seemingly ignores the data im pulling from the db.
all the log file saves is this for example-
Service is started at 8/24/2020 1:02:20 AM
Service is recalled at 8/24/2020 1:02:45 AM
Service is recalled at 8/24/2020 1:03:10 AM
Service is stopped at 8/24/2020 1:03:21 AM

and ideas on why the service is not reading the oracle data?

```
namespace WindowsService2
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(); // name space(using System.Timers;)  

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 25000; //number in milisecinds  
            timer.Enabled = true;

            
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is recalled at " + DateTime.Now);
            //create connection to oracle dB and connect to oracle dB without SQL*NET config file AKA TSANAMES.ORA
            string conString = "user id =user; password =1234;" + "data source = storage.database.com";
          
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

            con.ConnectionString = conString;
            con.Open();
            //create command within context of the connection and pull a record from the dB
            OracleCommand pullRecord = con.CreateCommand();
            pullRecord.CommandText = "select * from person where user_id='20'";
            // execute command and use reader to display data from table
            OracleDataReader reader = pullRecord.ExecuteReader();
            string str = reader[0].ToString();
            WriteToFile("user name " + str);
            con.Close();
            
        }

        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.   
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call reader.Read() method of DataReader

```
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     WriteToFile("Service is recalled at " + DateTime.Now);
     //create connection to oracle dB and connect to oracle dB without SQL*NET config file AKA TSANAMES.ORA
     string conString = "user id =user; password =1234;" + "data source = storage.database.com";
      
     OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

     con.ConnectionString = conString;
     con.Open();
     //create command within context of the connection and pull a record from the dB
     OracleCommand pullRecord = con.CreateCommand();
     pullRecord.CommandText = "select * from person where user_id='20'";
     // execute command and use reader to display data from table
     OracleDataReader reader = pullRecord.ExecuteReader();
     if(reader.HasRows)
     {
         if(reader.Read())
         {
             //Make sure data is not null . Otherwise your service will break.
             string str = reader.GetString(0);
             WriteToFile("user name " + str);
        }
     }
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: ah ty i knew i  forgot something!